# Remove first line from Textarea

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I have a tool that removes the blank lines from a confirmation (text) but for some reason there is a top line that is not being read as blank line and does not get deleted. 

Currently my tool allows a person to paste text into the textarea then when "remove spaces & copy" button is clicked blank lines are removed and text is copied to the clipboard. 

I want to keep the same function but somehow delete the first line either when text is entered into the textarea or when "remove spaces & copy" button is clicked.

```
 <script>
 function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var text = $(element).clone().find('br').prepend('\r\n').end().text()
  element = $('<textarea>').appendTo('body').val(text).select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  element.remove()
  }
  </script>
```

```
<textarea name="mas" rows="100" rows="50" contenteditable="true" id="p20" class="content" onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/[\n\r](?!\w)/gi,'');" style="height: 500px; width:800px;" type="text" data-bind="value: myValue, hasFocus: cleared"></textarea>
```

```
<!----------- BUTTONS ------------>
<div class="fixed">
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p20')" class="templateBtn">Remove Spaces & Copy</button>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: clearValue" value="clear" class="templateBtn" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
   myValue: ko.observable(''),
   cleared: ko.observable(false),
   clearValue: function() {       
   this.myValue('');   
   this.cleared(true);
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
   </script>

  <!----------- END.BUTTONS ------------>

 <div class="mas" id="hide" ></div>

 <pre contenteditable="true" id="p20" class="templateText">

 </div></div>
```

Comment: textareas have a special attribute called rows (and columns). That might be something to look at...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix you could use, perform a `trim()` on the replaced text:

```
<textarea name="mas" rows="100" rows="50" contenteditable="true"
id="p20" class="content"
onchange="this.value=(this.value.replace(/[\n\r](?!\w)/gi,'')).trim();"
style="height: 500px; width:800px;" type="text"
data-bind="value: myValue, hasFocus: cleared"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `[\n\r](?!\w)` matches any CR or LF not followed by an alphanumeric or underscore character. So it can match the first of two line terminators in a row when replacing blank lines with the null string. `''`  It doesn't match a line terminator followed by a letter. Hence a line terminator at the beginning of text, followed by a word character, is left in place.

Blank lines defined as "Start of line, followed by zero or more whitespace characters not including line terminators, followed by end of line, followed by zero or more line terminators" can be matched by a multi line regular expression such as:

```
/^[ \f\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]*$[\n\r]*/gm;
```

where the first character set is that used for matching whitespace (`\s`) after removing the line feed and carriage return characters, and the `$[\n\r]*` component matches both line terminators and end of input. (Edited: a trailing blank line without a line terminator at the end is matched)

Try it below by entering lines and clicking outside the textarea element to trigger a change event:

```js
function removeBlankLines( textArea) {
   var blankLine = /^[ \f\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]*$[\n\r]*/gm;
   textArea.value=textArea.value.replace(blankLine,'');
}
```

```html
<textarea onchange="removeBlankLines( this)" cols="20" rows="8"></textarea>
```

This does not trim or remove spaces within non-blank lines. If you are still having trouble achieving what you wish to do, please update the question with text data used to produce the problem and detailed description of what you expected and what you got. Please remove the knockout code if it not related to the question (it doesn't appear to be).